# Using Wildcards to Extract Text from Cell String Containing a Specific Value/Character

Tags: string, excel, extract, wildcard, worksheet-function

In a cell I have a string of text that contains both a Contact Name and Company Name (example in cell A2:  `John X. Doe, XYZ Inc.`).  I have successfully created a formula that uses the "_" (underscore character) that connects Company Name with ending Company Name Suffixes (i.e., `_Inc.`, `_Corporation`, `_LLC`, etc.).  This method connects the Company Name and Company Suffix together and treats the Company as one whole or complete word.

Example 1: Cell A2: `John X. Doe, XYZ Inc.`
Example 2: Cell B2:  `John X. Doe, XYZ_Inc.`

Trying to achieve the following:

Results 1: Cell C2: `John X. Doe`
Results 2: Cell D2: `XYZ_Inc.`

I would like to be able to extract (`XYZ_Inc.`) from the text string located in B2, using a wildcard expression (i.e. `"*"_"*"`) to extract/remove the Company Name located on the right from the Contact Name located on the left.  As you many know Company Names may vary and not consistent, thus the use of an ID character `_` and wildcard (asterisk `*`) may be appropriate if possible to identify and treat the connected Company Name as one word and remove.

Comment: Does the comma always separate the name from the company? If so, `Text-To-Columns` will split the two columns at each comma.

Comment: Hi User3561813.  Thanks for your reply and question.  No the Comma is not always used in most cases (i.e., Jane Doe ABC Inc.), the contact record does not possess a Comma, but does contain a Company Name Prefix (i.e., Inc.)  Also, I would like to use an MS Excel formula versus MS Excel's function tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try, in C2:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ","|",(LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ","")))),FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(B2," ","|",(LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ","")))))-1),",","")
```

in D2:

```
=MID(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ","|",(LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ","")))),FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(B2," ","|",(LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ","")))))+1,LEN(B2))
```

Comment: PNUTS.... THANK YOU, THANK YOU... AND THANK YOU... Your formula absolutely works, allowing me to extract the two Name Entities into separate fields based on the Criteria.  I would like to know, as when there is no data or in instances whereas the data does not contain a company name, how do I remove the #VALUE! error message from appearing and return with either or a Blank "" or Zero "0" value?